# How to bind a Button Column through the Datatable. And Bind that Datatable to Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I want to Know

> How to Bind a Button Column through the `DataTable` and Bind that
>   `DataTable` to `Datagridview` ?

Here i am Using `Checkbox`
to Select the Row i want to replace that using Button. Is there any possible Ways?

`Datatabe` Initialization:-

```
 orderTable = new DataTable();
 orderTable.Rows.Clear();
 orderTable.Clear();
 orderTable.Columns.Add("Select", typeof(bool));
 orderTable.Columns.Add("Time");
 orderTable.Columns.Add("Date");
 orderTable.Columns.Add("Order#");
 orderTable.Columns.Add("CustName");
 orderTable.Columns.Add("Product");
 orderTable.Columns.Add("Imagepath");
 orderTable.Columns.Add("datetime");
```

Binding Row:-

```
 DataRow Drorder = orderTable.NewRow();
 Drorder["Select"] = false;
 Drorder["Time"] = time;
 Drorder["Date"] = date;
 Drorder["Order#"] = ordernumber;
 Drorder["CustName"] = Name;
 Drorder["Product"] = prodcutname;
 Drorder["Imagepath"] = pathf;
 Drorder["datetime"] = folderDatetime;
 orderTable.Rows.Add(Drorder);
 Orders.DataSource = orderTable;
```

The Following Method gives an error..

> Specified Cast is  Not Valid

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn);
btn.HeaderText = "Test Button";
btn.Text = "Test Btn";
btn.Name = "btn";
btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;`
```

Comment: anyone thererrr

Comment: anyone there to